# NSDictionary to File

Tags: ios, caching, nsdictionary

I have been working on a SOAP Web Service that uses a Caché to avoid HTTP requests when they have been done before.

When I try to save my NSDictionary to a file I get a error (I guess it is because it doesn't follow the Properties List structure) and I know how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
[self loadCache];
NSData *responseData;
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [_cache objectForKey:delegate.type];

if (dict != nil && [dict objectForKey:request.HTTPBody] != nil ) {
    responseData = [dict objectForKey:request.HTTPBody];
} else {
    NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil; 
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];  
    responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
    if (dict == nil) {
        dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [_cache setObject:dict forKey:delegate.type];
        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:NSTimeIntervalSince1970] forKey:@"FECHA"];
    }
    if (responseData == nil) {
        responseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"xml"]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", [[request.HTTPBody copy] class]);
    [dict setObject:responseData forKey:request.HTTPBody];

    [self saveCache];
}
```

loadCache Function:

```
- (void)loadCache {
if (_loadedCache) return;
NSString* docsurl = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
docsurl = [docsurl stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cache.txt"];
_cache = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:docsurl];
if (_cache == nil) _cache = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
```

saveCache Function:

```
- (void)saveCache {
NSString* docsurl = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
docsurl = [docsurl stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cache.txt"];
if ([_cache writeToFile:docsurl atomically:YES]) {
    NSLog(@"SAVED");
} else {
    NSLog(@"ERROR");
}
}
```

Comment: Solved! I was trying to use NSData as KEY, and it can only be used as VALUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented: Solved! I was trying to use NSData as KEY, and it can only be used as VALUE.

Answer (score 0):

NSData cannot be the "key" it is only able to be the "value"